# Vimgrep before any empty line

Tags: regex, vim, vimgrep

I have a lot of files which starts with some tags I defined.

Example:

```
=Title
@context
!todo
#topic
#subject
#etc

And some text (notice the blank line just before this text).

Foo
Bar
```

I'd like to write a Vim search command (with vimgrep) to match something before an empty line.

How do I grep only in the lines before the first blank line? Will it make quicker grep action? Please, no need to mention `:grep` and binary like `Ag - silver search`.

I know `\_.*` to match everything including EOL. I know the negation `[^foo]`. I succeed to match everything but empty lines with `/[^^$]`. But I didn't manage to compose my :vimgrep command. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a **general solution** which works **for any content of file** let me tell you that AFAK, **you can't** with that form of text. You may ask why ?

---

- ### Explanation:

---

`vimgrep` requires a pattern argument to do the search **line by line** which behaves exactly as the `:global` cmd.

For your case we need to get the first part preceding the first blank line. (*It can be extended to: Get the first non blank text*)

Let's call:

- **A**  :Every block of text not containing any single blank line inside
- **x**  :Blank lines

With these only **5** forms of content file you can get the first A block with `vimgrep`(case 2,4,5 are obvious):

> **1** | `2` | **3** | `4` | **5**
>
> ---
>
> **x** | `x` | **A** | `x` |  **A**
>
> **A** | `A` | **x** | `A`  | **x**
>
> **x** | `x`  | **A**
>
> **A** |

Looking to your file, it is having this form:

> A
>
> x
>
> **A**
>
> x
>
> A

the middle block causes a problem that's why you cannot split the first **`A`** **unless you delimit it by some known UNIQUE text**.

---

So the **only solution** that I can come up for the only **5 cases** is:

```
:vimgrep /\_.\{-}\(\(\n\s*\n\)\+\)\@=/ %
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the most you can do with `:vimgrep` is use the `\%<XXl` atom to search below a specific line number:

```
:vim /\%<20lfunction/ *.vim
```

That command will find all instances of `function` above line 20 in the given files.

See `:help \%l`.

Answer (score -1):

`[...]` always matches a single character. `[^^$]` matches a character that is not `^` or `$`. This is not what you want.

---

One of the things you can do is:

```
/\%^\%(.\+\n\)\{-}.\{-}\zsfoo/
```

This matches

- `\%^` - the beginning of the file
- `\%(` `\)` - a non-capturing group
- `\{-}` - ... repeated 0 or more times (as few as possible)
- `.\+` - 1 or more non-newline characters
- `\n` - a newline
- `.\{-}` - 0 or more non-newline characters (as few as possible)
- `\zs` - the official start of the match

This will find the first occurrence of `foo`, starting from the beginning of the file, searching only non-empty lines. But that's all it does: You can't use it to find multiple matches.

---

Alternatively:

```
/\%(^\n\_.*\)\@<!foo/
```

- `\%(` `\)` - a non-capturing group
- `\@<!` - not-preceded-by modifier
- `^` - beginning of line
- `\n` - newline
- `\_.*` - 0 or more of any character

This matches every occurrence of `foo` that is not preceded anywhere by an empty line (i.e. a beginning-of-line / newline combo).